# Stack Overflow error Jquery

Tags: jquery

HI All,

I am using jquery-1.4.1.js file but when i  open application in I.E.8 it is throwing error "Stack Overflow occur at line 2734 Out of stack space" but it seems running smoothly on FireFox.

Code lines are as below-:

```
if ( left.substr( left.length - 1 ) !== "\\" ) {
    match[1] = (match[1] || "").replace(/\\/g, "");
    set = Expr.find[ type ]( match, context, isXML );
    if ( set != null ) {
        expr = expr.replace( Expr.match[ type ], "" );
        break;
    }
```

Here in this code "`set = Expr.find[ type ]( match, context, isXML );`" is a line no. 2734.

What could be reason. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your stack is running out of memory. Memory is allocated but isn't deallocated - most probably because of an infinite loop.

Can we see the code on and around line 2734?

Comment: Hi Alex
Code lines are as follows -:

if ( left.substr( left.length - 1 ) !== "\\" ) {
    match[1] = (match[1] || "").replace(/\\/g, "");
   set = Expr.find[ type ]( match, context, isXML );
if ( set != null ) {
expr = expr.replace( Expr.match[ type ], "" );
 break;
    }
Here in this code "set = Expr.find[ type ]( match, context, isXML );" is a line no. 2734. 

Please Help

Comment: @user430546 Please edit the code into your original question.

Comment: Alex i have added the code lines to my original question.

Thanks